# Camera Messes Up Textures When Zooming

Tags: animation, camera

So I've had this problem for a long time, and what happens is that the camera, when zooming in or out, makes textures very jumpy. It is always adjusting and it's very weird. I don't know if this is because I've set the clipping to the max (End clipping being 10000), but it looks very bad. Any ways tp fix this? Thanks!

Comment: What is you start clipping? If set too low, it will result in clipping errors.

Comment: Near and far clipping values should be as close as possible for your scene

Comment: My start clipping is the default 0.100.